# SharePoint Help

Tags: central-administration, 2016

Open CA at first time display

[image]

Which option to select? what is the benefit of each option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the same as in all these inquiries of software producer saying "allow that your system gives us information". 
Which option to select? => No! 
Benefit? => that Microsoft can get as much debug information as possible!
Your benefit? => None!

Comment: Thanks for quick help, what's  Customer Experience Improvement program  ?

Comment: you can first read the link "More info"